# how to extract src as a jar when classpath is in a referenced library?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a bunch of java files and my launch config uses the main class in an external library. I'm having no luck with exporting it as a jar though. When I try to select a path for my main class, nothing shows up. But I can launch my program fine through eclipse. Is this even possible to do?

here is my manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ sb-vit-api.jar sb-vital-framework.jar vital-client.jar
Class-Path: .
```

I want to access the classfile called Loader.class which sits inside sb-vital-framework.jar inside a package called simple.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have your own main class. For example, CallLoader.java. This class should have a static main method where it can instantiate and call your external Loader class. Run your CallLoader class (right click/Run as.../Java Application). This will create a Launch Configuration.

After this is working:

Right-click on the project and select Export... Then select Java/Runnable Jar. Pick your launch configuration and choose an export destination e.g. `myjar.jar`. On the command line, you can run your Jar as `java -jar myjar.jar`.

If you want to directly call your external main then you may edit the MANIFEST in the jar to make that main the main main. :)

Comment: hey thanks! i've edited my question to include details about the manifest file. I'm not sure where and how exactly to specify the main class.

Comment: I updated my answer. Otherwise, google "ëclipse runnable jar". Plenty of examples.